# Selecting image from library doesn't call "didFinishPickingImage" function - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a UIImagePickerController with the option to select from library.

When the `accessLibrary` button is called, it prompts another UIImagePickerController that has source type `.PhotoLibrary`.

```
func accessLibrary(sender: UIButton!) {
    NSLog("access library")
    choseFromLibrary = true
    self.libraryPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    self.libraryPicker!.allowsEditing = false
    self.libraryPicker!.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    self.presentViewController(self.libraryPicker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This all works well, but when the user does select a photo, I want to pass that image to a view and then show that view on the screen.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let metadata = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] as? NSDictionary
    var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    if (image != nil) {
        if (choseFromLibrary) {
            let cnfrmImgView = ConfirmImageView.init(image: image!)
            self.view.addSubview(cnfrmImgView)
        }
        else {
            if (frontFacing) {
                image! = UIImage(CGImage: image!.CGImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: .LeftMirrored)
            }
            let cnfrmImgView = ConfirmImageView.init(image: image!)
            self.view.addSubview(cnfrmImgView)
        }
    }
}
```

The above function works if the image is taken using the camera, but not using the library.

When a user picks a photo from the library, the library picker controller just dismisses itself and the view is not display.

I ran an `NSLog("here")` to check if the `didFinishPickingImageWithInfo` function is called when choosing from the library and in fact it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`didFinishPickingImageWithInfo` is a delegate message ([UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:)). The problem, however, is that you have not given your image picker any `delegate`! Thus, it has no one to send delegate messages to.

Comment: If you think Xcode's Mental Telepathy API is not working properly, file a bug report with Apple! :)

Comment: If I solved the problem, please consider accepting my answer (checkmark). I notice that you are not in the habit of accepting answers, and while it's none of my business, I must warn you that that can hold you back on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement a Instagram like image picker than try this

[Image Picker like Instagram](https://github.com/wenzhaot/InstagramPhotoPicker)

Answer (score 0):

The delegate function is updated in new swift versions from 4 to upwards.
Use this function instead

`func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) { }`